# LinqToEntities query for records with NO join

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have `TableA` listing purchase orders.  I have `TableB` listing Inbound Shipments.  Each shipment record references a purchase order.  What I want is a LinqToSql clause that will return those purchase order records from `TableA` that are not yet on a shipment.  In SQL this would be simple:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderID NOT IN (SELECT OrderID FROM Shipments).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming DbSets called PurchaseOrders and Shipments then something like this should suffice:

```
db.PurchaseOrders.Where(
    p => !db.Shipments.Select(s => s.OrderID).Contains(p.OrderID)
)
```